# How to fix " '}' expected " with a list

Tags: lua, computercraft

I am making a simple list variable and trying to print it, however I receive an error stating that I am missing an end bracket.

I already tried to wrap the entire variable with brackets, but to no avail.

Code:

```
local list = {0 = "Alpha", 1 = "Beta"}
print (list[0])
```

Error message:

```
bios:14: [string ".temp"]:1: '}' expected
```

Comment: Try this: `local list = {[0] = "Alpha", [1] = "Beta"}`

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by tonypdmtr. I forgot to put brackets around the integers.